# How to resolve error "cannot resolve method getItemAtPosition(int)".

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

My code is that when i select an item on list, the item name should pass as toolbar for next screen.

So while I'm passing the selected item by calling function putExtra(), in that I'm getting error on getItemAtPosition(i) like "cannot resolve method getItemAtPosition(int)

here is my code...

package com.example.hp.shapes;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class secondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar mtoolbar;
    ListView l;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        mtoolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar2);

        Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
        if(bundle!=null)
        {
            mtoolbar.setTitle(bundle.getString("shapeName"));
            if(mtoolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Square"))
            {
                l=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
                ArrayAdapter<String> m1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(secondActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.square));

               /* l.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l)*/


 l.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                   Intent intent1=new Intent(secondActivity.this,ThirdActivity.class);
                   intent1.putExtra("squareName", intent1.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
                   startActivity(intent1);

               }
           });
            l.setAdapter(m1);


        }
            else if(mtoolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("rectangle"))
            {
                l=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
                ArrayAdapter<String> m1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(secondActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.rectangle));

                l.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                        Intent i1=new Intent(secondActivity.this,ThirdActivity.class);
                        i1.putExtra("rectangleName",l.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
                        startActivity(i1);
                    }
                });
                l.setAdapter(m1);

            }
            else if(mtoolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("parallelogram"))
            {
                l=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
                ArrayAdapter<String> m1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(secondActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.parallelogram));

                l.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                        Intent i1=new Intent(secondActivity.this,ThirdActivity.class);
                        i1.putExtra("Name1",l.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
                        startActivity(i1);
                    }
                });
                l.setAdapter(m1);

            }
            else if(mtoolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("hexagon"))
            {
                l=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
                ArrayAdapter<String> m1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(secondActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.hexagon));

                l.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                        Intent i1=new Intent(secondActivity.this,ThirdActivity.class);
                        i1.putExtra("Name1",l.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
                        startActivity(i1);
                    }
                });
                l.setAdapter(m1);

            }
            else if(mtoolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("octagon"))
            {
                l=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
                ArrayAdapter<String> m1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(secondActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.octagon));

                l.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                        Intent i1=new Intent(secondActivity.this,ThirdActivity.class);
                        i1.putExtra("Name1",l.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
                        startActivity(i1);
                    }
                });
                l.setAdapter(m1);

            }
            else if(mtoolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("pentagon"))
            {
                l=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
                ArrayAdapter<String> m1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(secondActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.pentagon));

                l.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                        Intent i1=new Intent(secondActivity.this,ThirdActivity.class);
                        i1.putExtra("Name1",l.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
                        startActivity(i1);
                    }
                });
                l.setAdapter(m1);

            }
            else if(mtoolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("cube"))
            {
                l=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
                ArrayAdapter<String> m1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(secondActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cube));

                l.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                        Intent i1=new Intent(secondActivity.this,ThirdActivity.class);
                        i1.putExtra("Name1",l.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
                        startActivity(i1);
                    }
                });
                l.setAdapter(m1);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `getItemAtPosition()` method on `Intent`. There *is* one on `ListView`.

Compare:

```
intent1.putExtra("squareName", intent1.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
```

with:

```
i1.putExtra("rectangleName",l.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
```

In the first case, you are calling `getItemAtPosition()` on `intent1`, which is an `Intent`. This will not compile.

In the second case, you are calling `getItemAtPosition()` on `l`, which is a `ListView`. This will compile.